# `sources` in .gemrc file appears to not be working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I cloned a repo with a very simple Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem "rspec"
```

Running `bundle install` threw this error:

```
$ bundle install
Your Gemfile has no gem server sources. If you need gems that are not already on your
machine, add a line like this to your Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'
Could not find rspec-support-3.2.2 in any of the sources
```

Not wanting to modify the Gemfile, I created `~/.gemrc` like so:

```
# ~/.gemrc
sources:
- http://rubygems.org
```

Then, I closed and reopened the shell window.

The error did not change. The error resolved when I added `source "http://rubygems.org"` to the `Gemfile`.

Why didn't updating the `.gemrc` file resolve the error?

Comment: Update bundler.  Newer versions do not require the `source` directive and default to `https://rubygems.org

Comment: I have the most recent version, 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is:

```
- sources:
+ :sources:
   - https://rubygems.org/
```

see https://ruby-doc.org/current/stdlibs/rubygems/Gem/ConfigFile.html